# Change individual node size using Dash-Cytoscape

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, cytoscape

I've been using Dash-Cytoscape for two days now and I tried a lot of things to change the node size individually. 
I tried this but it didn't work:

```
import dash
import dash_cytoscape as cyto
import dash_html_components as html

app = dash.Dash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div([
    cyto.Cytoscape(
        id="cytospace",
        elements=[
            {'data': {'id': 'one', 'label': 'Node 1'}, 'position': {'x': 50, 'y': 50}, 'size':20},
            {'data': {'id': 'two', 'label': 'Node 2'}, 'position': {'x': 200, 'y': 200}, 'size':70},
            {'data': {'source': 'one', 'target': 'two','label': 'Node 1 to 2'}}
        ],
        layout={'name':'preset'},
        style={'height': '95vh',
               'width': '100%'}
    )
])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me the following code allows to adjust the node size:

```
import dash
import dash_cytoscape as cyto
import dash_html_components as html

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

default_stylesheet = [
    {
        'selector': 'node',
        'style': {
            'background-color': '#BFD7B5',
            'label': 'data(label)',
            'width': "30%",
            'height': "50%"
        }
    }
]

app.layout = html.Div([
    cyto.Cytoscape(
        id="cytospace",
        elements=[
            {'data': {'id': 'one', 'label': 'Node 1'}, 'position': {'x': 50, 'y': 50}, 'size':20},
            {'data': {'id': 'two', 'label': 'Node 2'}, 'position': {'x': 200, 'y': 200}, 'size':70},
            {'data': {'source': 'one', 'target': 'two','label': 'Node 1 to 2'}}
        ],
        layout={'name':'preset'},
        stylesheet=default_stylesheet
    )
])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: When I run this code the nodes remain the same size. Do you have any clue what could be the reason for this?

Comment: I ran this code exactly and the nodes are the same size.

Comment: Same. This code doesn't work.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a more detailed and general version. You can change individual node size via css styling. You can edit the width and height attribute for an individual node. If you have already stored size in elements data, map stored data to node size using [mappers](https://js.cytoscape.org/#style/mappers). Here is what I find on Cytoscape.js documentation.

> `mapData()` specifies a linear mapping to an element’s data field. For example, `mapData(weight, 0, 100, blue, red)` maps an element’s weight to colours between blue and red for weights between 0 and 100. An element with `ele.data("weight") === 0` would be mapped to blue, for instance. Elements whose values fall outside of the specified range are mapped to the extremity values. In the previous example, an element with `ele.data("weight") === -1` would be mapped to blue.

```py
import dash
import dash_cytoscape as cyto
import dash_html_components as html

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

default_stylesheet = [
    {
        "selector": "node",
        "style": {
            "width": "mapData(size, 0, 100, 20, 60)",
            "height": "mapData(size, 0, 100, 20, 60)",
            "content": "data(label)",
            "font-size": "12px",
            "text-valign": "center",
            "text-halign": "center",
        }
    }
]

app.layout = html.Div([
    cyto.Cytoscape(
        id="cytospace",
        elements=[
            {'data': {'id': 'one', 'label': 'Node 1', 'size': 10}, 'position': {'x': 50, 'y': 50}},
            {'data': {'id': 'two', 'label': 'Node 2', 'size': 120}, 'position': {'x': 200, 'y': 200}},
            {'data': {'source': 'one', 'target': 'two','label': 'Node 1 to 2'}}
        ],
        layout={'name':'preset'},
        stylesheet=default_stylesheet
    )
])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Spent hours in the documentation and on videos on YouTube